# Handling missing types in PCL with real types existing on some of the platforms

Tags: c#, types, windows-runtime, windows-phone, portable-class-library

This may be a question answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I am working on a project to port Mono.Data.Sqlite to Windows Phone and Windows Store, but of course this requires System.Data to be ported as well.
I decided to use PCLs as this removes the need for separate assemblies for the platforms (I am also checking out Silverlight, but this is not a priority)
In doing this, I have managed to get most of the functionality across except for one type - DBNull :(

This is where the problem is, WP and SL have the DBNull declared, but WinRT does not. Is it possible to do something in the single assembly to use the native DBNull on the platforms where it exists (WP and SL) and use a custom implementation on WinRT?
I haven't seemed to find a way to do this. I have looked at other solutions: (a) create a PCL for SL and WP and exclude the DBNull type and another assembly for WinRT, or (b) create a single assembly that references a custom assembly for WP and SL with type forwarding to the native implementation of DBNull, and an assembly for RT with the implementation of DBNull.

Is there any other ways, or which one is better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this by using strong named assemblies and the [TypeForwardedToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute.aspx).

First, give your PCL assembly a strong name by signing it, preferably by adding an `AssemblyKeyFileAttribute` to the *AssemblyInfo.cs* file. More details are found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx).

Next, add a simple `DBNull` class with sufficient contents. Here is an example, modify it to your own content:

```
namespace System
{
  public sealed class DBNull
  {
    public static readonly DBNull Value = new DBNull();
    private DBNull() { }
  }
}
```

Now, you will need to create target specific assemblies with the same *strong* name and version as the PCL assembly. These assemblies will replace the PCL assembly in the target specific applications making use of `DBNull`. If this should work, it is absolutely necessary that the strong name and version are the same. If the signing file is referenced in the *AssemblyInfo.cs* file of the PCL project, one efficient approach is simply to add (with a link) this file to the target specific project instead of the auto-generated *AssemblyInfo.cs* file. Also, in the project settings, make sure that the assembly name is the same for the target specific and PCL libraries.

In the .NET Framework and Windows Phone libraries replacing the PCL library, you should now add a *.cs* file, for example called *TypeForwarding.cs*, with the following contents:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(DBNull))]
```

When this assembly is referenced (replacing the PCL assembly), the compiler will then know that it should look for the existing `DBNull` implementation in the target framework.

On the other hand, in the Windows Store (WinRT) library replacing the PCL, you should include the same `DBNull` source file that you included in the PCL library, since WinRT does *not* contain a pre-existing implementation of `DBNull`.

**EDIT**

First of all, a very important note! If you are using `TypeForwardedToAttribute`, the method or property signature in the PCL assembly must be *exactly the same* as the signature in the target specific consumer assembly. Otherwise the method/property will not be properly identified in the end-user application. I usually consult the MSDN documentation to obtain the correct signatures.

It also crucial that if you are using type forwarding for `enum` types, the numeric values of the enums must be equal to the target specific implementations. A resource that is very helpful when identifying these values is the [Mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono).

Whether you should use non-functional stubs in your PCL assembly varies from type to type, and as far as I know there is no specific support for generating consumer project assemblies from a PCL.

For example, there are some types that are available on the three targets *.NET*, *Windows Store* and *Windows Phone 8*, but **not** in PCL, like the `Marshal` and `GCHandle` classes. In this case you would provide unimplemented methods in your PCL like this:

```
public static class Marshal
{
  public static IntPtr AllocHGlobal(int cb) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

and then use type forwarding in all your consumer libraries:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(Marshal))]
```

On the other hand, there are types that are available on some but not all of the targets, and not in PCL.

In that case, if it is appropriate, you can include a working implementation in the PCL (as suggested in the original answer) and include that same implementation in the  consumer project for the target that is missing this type.

If it impractical or impossible to provide a PCL implementation that works with any target, you could instead include a non-functional stub in the PCL, and provide a target specific implementation in the consumer projects.

Comment: Thanks Anders! This is good stuff here! Just a few questions, I am getting from here that the PCL will contain "stubs"? And the platform specifics contain the implementation which will replace the stubs for the consumer projects? Is there a way to create those stub classes automatically as there will be quite a few? Or do we just link in the common source files to the PCL as well as the specifics?

Comment: @Matthew I have provided an edit that hopefully will give you the additional answers you need.

Comment: Hi @AndersGustafsson, I'm trying this approach in that other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248514/xamarin-forms-and-entityframework-attributes-compatibility, but cannot make it work. Help needed! :)

Answer (score 3):

While Anders approach is technically sound (and is exactly how we implemented the "modern" surface area of .NET Core) it is not free of challenges.

If you're only using this approach for libraries that you reuse from your own applications then it can work very well. However, if you want to ship your component to 3rd parties, for example, via NuGet then this approach doesn't scale as the ecosystem has to agree on what is ***the one representation*** on the platforms that don't include the type already. That's why we keep shipping portability packs, such `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` where we do that work for the community.

`System.Data` is on our radar, in particular `System.Data.Common` so that we can enable 3rd party SQL providers, such as SQLite, to share the abstractions and common utilities (`DBNull`) across all platforms. We don't have an ETA for that work, but it's certainly on our TODO list.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I am in the process of Portablizing my version of the System.Data assemblies: https://github.com/mattleibow/mono.Data.SQLite :) I ripped out the DataSet and SqlClient as it was mainly going to be used for SQLite, but I may have to put it back in the near future. How would you guys go about making the System.Data portable? Would you create a Ms.Bcl.Data and then type forward the stuff to the existing libraries and use those types in Ms.Bcl.Data for say WP?

Comment: If you want to see an example, have a look a the `Microsoft.Bcl` NuGet package. Basically, we'd define a new assembly for the common core, such as `System.Data.Common.dll`. We'd ship two implementations. One for full framework, which just type forwards to `System.Data` and one that is a self contained implementation in a portable class library. At install time, NuGet will select the correct implementation based on the project's target framework.