# Use System.Net.Sockets in PCL (.Net 4.5 + phone 8)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, portable-class-library

I have existing .Net libraries which work already for .Net 4.5 and Windows Phone 8.
Now I would like to convert this in a portable class library and suddenly I can't use `System.Net.Sockets` anymore.

I only cheched .Net 4.5 and windows phone 8. Xbox/store app/silverlight is not selected.
Xamarin is automaticly selected because it has the same requirements.

I can avoid sockets by using interfaces and stuff, but why can't I use it if they both support it?

There are other questions on stackoverflow about this but these use xbox or metro apps.

Comment: A while back I gave an answer to a similar question, please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21368529/650012) for a suggestion on what you could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the WinRT API is added to PCL:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4443287-make-winrt-api-usable-in-portable-class-libraries

> **Make WinRT API usable in Portable Class Libraries targeting Windows 8 and WP8**
>
> That’s a great suggestion. We’ve added this capability for the new
> versions of both platforms. So when you author a portable class
> libraries with the following targets (or any subset) you’ll have
> access to WinRT APIs as well:
>
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows Phone 8.1
> - Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 For the first two platforms, you’re also able to produce Windows Runtime components (WinMD).
>
> Immo Landwerth
> Program Manager
> .NET Framework Team

You need VS2013 Update 2 for this.
Here some more info about this update:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/04/02/visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-universal-projects-for-windows-and-windows-phone.aspx

Sockets in WinRT is in the `Windows.Networking.Sockets` namespace:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226960.aspx