# Cannot find System.Net.Sockets assembly for WP 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create an app which works as a remote-control for my musicplayer. I've just finished written a nice library for my code and I just now noticed there is no assembly called System.Net.Sockets for Windows Phone 8.1?
There must be a solution to this, but I just cannot find it. Does anyone know how I might be able to import it to my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874(v=vs.105).aspx), you should be using `Windows.Networking.Sockets` instead:

> The Windows Runtime API, Windows.Networking.Sockets, has been adopted
>   for Windows Phone 8. It has been implemented as a Windows Phone
>   Runtime API, making it easy to use in whatever supported programming
>   language you choose. Although we've enhanced the .NET API,
>   System.Net.Sockets, to support more features such as IPv6 and listener
>   sockets, you should consider using the new API for sockets programming
>   because it is more portable than the .NET API.
>   Windows.Networking.Sockets has been built from the ground up to be
>   clean, secure, and easy-to-use APIs that enforce best practices.

In WinRT, this is what you need to do. Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22891015/1346943) to a related question for further reading.

Comment: Is not it for Windows store app?

Comment: Wow.. Seems like I've wasted quite a lot of time building this for nothing then. From what I've seen you have to change quite a lot of things in order to get it working. But, thank you.