# System.Net.Sockets not found in WP8.1 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Brand new Windows Phone 8.1 project in C#, VS2013 update 4. The `using System.Net.Sockets` line gives a compilation error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Sockets' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The System.Net assembly is not available in the References dialog - it claims all possible assemblies have been already referenced. Trying to browse to it produces a message that the assembly is already referenced in the project.

What am I missing, please?

EDIT: in a project that's explicitly targeting WP8.0 (the template is called "Windows Phone Silverlight" as opposed to "Windows Phone") the namespace in question is available.

Comment: did you add a reference to `System.Net.Sockets`?

Comment: Can't find such an assembly. The docs claim the Sockets namespace is in System.Net.dll

Comment: And you have the `using` statement? or fully qualified types? Please show some code.

Comment: `Using` alone causes the error.

Comment: I think it's Windows.Networking.Sockets on WP 8.1. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477961/cannot-find-system-net-sockets-assembly-for-wp-8-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer: `System.Net.Sockets` is not supported on Windows Phone 8.1

Use `Windows.Networking.Sockets` instead. Documentation available here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.aspx